# C# immutable object setter understanding

Tags: c#, immutability, immutable-collections

I have immutable class F1. And i want to change one of it's field. In set method i must return new instance of F1 class with changing. I doesn't understand how i can do this.

```
public class F1
{
    public readonly int k1;
    public readonly ImmutableList<int> k2;

    public F1(int k)
    {
        ...
    }

    public int GetItem(int pos)
    {
        return k2[pos];
    }

    public F1 SetItem(int pos, int val)
    {
        return new F1() // How i can create new instance with changes in pos
    }
}
```

There is Replace method in String.cs. String is immutable class in C# (or i think so). Replace method define like this:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private string ReplaceInternal(char oldChar, char newChar);

[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
{
  return this.ReplaceInternal(oldChar, newChar);
}
```

So i don't know how works ReplaceInternal and then can't find answer for my question.

Comment: How is `k2` constructed? You need to create a complete, new instance of `F1`, with all fields set at construction time.

Comment: `F1 f = new F1(){k2 = this.k2 , k1 = this.k1};` then make the changes in `f`. and return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what exactly you are trying to do in the constructor but you can add another constructor that accepts an ImmutableList like Kryzsztof has shown and modify the SetItem method like so:

```
public F1 SetItem(int pos, int val)
{
    return new F1(k1, k2.SetItem(pos, val));
}
```

Full implementation:

```
public class F1
{
    public readonly int k1;
    public readonly ImmutableList<int> k2;

    public F1(int k)
    {
        ...
    }

    private F1(int k1, ImmutableList<int> k2)
    {
        this.k1 = k1;
        this.k2 = k2;
    }

    public int GetItem(int pos)
    {
        return k2[pos];
    }

    public F1 SetItem(int pos, int val)
    {
        return new F1(k1, k2.SetItem(pos, val));
    }
}
```

Note, that I made the new constructor private, assuming that you didn't want to expose this constructor for anything other than this purpose.

Edit:
I should also note that the semantics of ImmutableList are such that any modification to the list using your typical list methods results in a new list, such as this call to SetItem:

```
k2.SetItem(pos, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have constructor that looks like this:

```
public F1(int k1, ImmutableList<int> k2)
{
    this.k1 = k1;
    this.k2 = k2;
}
```

You can create methods to modify properties by creating and returning new object with changed properties instead of mutating current one.

```
public F1 SetK1(int newk1)
{
    return new F1(newk1, this.k2);
}

public F1 SetK2(ImmutableList<int> newK2)
{
    return new F1(this.k1, newK2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basing your solution on String's `Replace` method, which might not be the best idea. StackOverflow history shows that people, especially newcomers to the .NET framework, routinely misunderstand the semantics of `String.Replace`, since its syntax does not imply immutability, and you're forced to rely on external documentation or prior knowledge.

Instead of creating setters/Set methods which do not, in fact, set values, I would create a method called "GetModifiedCopy", which explicitly returns a new copy with the modified values. This

```
public class F1
{
    public readonly int k1;

    public F1(int k1)
    {
      ...
    }

    public F1 GetModifiedCopy(int newVal)
    {
        return new F1(newVal);
    }
}
```

Now, your situation is a bit more complex, since you're not just instantiating a new instance with a single value, but you're copying the entire existing list and modifying one value. However, the solution is the same - create a private constructor that receives the original list and the new value, modify the list in the constructor, and return the new instance.

```
private F1(ImmutableList<int> baseList, int pos, int value)
{
    var tempList = baseList.ToList(); // create mutable list.
    tempList[pos] = value; // modify list.
    this.k2 = new ImmutableList<int>(tempList); // immutablize!
}
public F1 GetModifiedCopy(int pos, int value)
{
    return new F1(this.k2, pos, value);
}
```